# How to get linux ebpf assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel

I want to learn linux ebpf vm, if I write a ebpf program test.c, used llvm:
clang -O2 -target bpf -o test.o test.c. How to get the ebpf assembly like tcpdump -d in classic bpf, thanks.

Comment: Show a small example of what the output from `tcpdump` looks like. I would suspect it's probably similar to `objdump -d`

Comment: Like this: `# tcpdump -i any -d ip  
(000) ldh [14]
(001) jeq #0x800 jt 2 jf 3
(002) ret #65535
(003) ret #0`

Comment: @JunliOu `tcpdump -d` will print the instructions in the old BPF (a.k.a. _cBPF_) format. Hint: with `tcpdump -ddd` each displayed instruction has 4 fields (there are 5 with eBPF).

Answer (score 17):

This depends on what you mean exactly by “learn[ing] linux ebpf vm”.

## The language itself

If you mean learning about **the instructions of eBPF,** the assembly-like language itself, you can have a look at [the documentation from the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt) (quite dense) or at [this summarized version of the syntax](https://github.com/iovisor/bpf-docs/blob/master/eBPF.md) from bcc project.

## The virtual machine

If you prefer to see how **the internals of the eBPF virtual machine** work, you can either have a look at various presentations (I recommend those from D. Borkmann), I have a list here [in this blog post](https://qmonnet.github.io/whirl-offload/2016/09/01/dive-into-bpf/#about-bpf); or you can directly read at the kernel sources, under `linux/kernel/bpf` (in particular file [`core.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/core.c)). Alternatively, there is a [simpler userspace implementation](https://github.com/iovisor/ubpf/) available.

## Dump eBPF instructions

Now if you want to see the code that has been compiled from C to eBPF, here are a couple of solutions.

#### Read the object file

For my part I compile with the command presented in the [`tc-bpf` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-bpf.8.html):

```
__bcc() {
        clang -O2 -emit-llvm -c $1 -o - | \
        llc -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o "`basename $1 .c`.o"
}
alias bcc=__bcc
```

The code is translated into eBPF and stored in one of the sections of the ELF file produced. Then I can examine my program with tools such as `objdump` or `readelf`. For example, if my program is in the `classifier` section:

```
$ bcc return_zero.c
$ readelf -x classifier return_zero.o

Hex dump of section 'classifier':
   0x00000000 b7000000 02000000 95000000 00000000 ................
```

In the above output, two instructions are displayed (little endian — the first field starting with `0x` is the offset inside the section). We could parse this to put in shape the instructions and to obtain:

```
b7 0 0 0000 00000002 // Load 0x02 in register r0
95 0 0 0000 00000000 // Exit and return value in r0
```

#### [April 2019 edit] Dump an eBPF program loaded in the kernel

It is possible to dump the instructions of programs loaded (and then possibly attached to one of the available BPF hooks) in the kernel, either as eBPF assembly instructions, or as machine instructions if the program has been JIT-compiled. [bpftool](https://www.mankier.com/package/bpftool), relying on libbpf, is the go-to utility for doing such things. For example, one can see what programs are currently loaded, and note their ids, with:

```
# bpftool prog show
```

Then dumping the instructions for a program of a given id is as simple as:

```
# bpftool prog dump xlated id <id>
# bpftool prog dump jited  id <id>
```

for eBPF or JITed (if available) instructions respectively. Output can also be formatted as JSON if necessary.

#### Advanced tools

Depending on the tools you use to inject BPF into the kernel, you can generally dump the output of the in-kernel verifier, that contains most of the instructions formatted in a human-friendly way.

With the [bcc set of tools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) (not directly related to the previous command, and not related at all with the old 16-bit compiler), you can get this [by using the relevant flags](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/c085977ebdde38a340ff503c9161e82fb0fff0b9/src/python/bcc/__init__.py#L196) for the BPF object instance, while with `tc filter add dev eth0 bpf obj … verbose` this is done with the `verbose` keyword.

#### Disassemblers

The aforementioned userspace implementation ([uBPF](https://github.com/iovisor/ubpf/tree/master/ubpf)) has its own assembler and disassembler that might be of interest to you: it takes the “human-friendly” (`add32 r0, r1` and the likes) instructions as input and converts into object files, or the other way round, respectively.

But probably more interesting, there is the support for debug info, coming along with a BPF disassembler, in LLVM itself: as of today it has recently been merged, and its author (A. Starovoitov) has sent [an email](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg406926.html) about it on the netdev mailing list. This means that with clang/LLVM 4.0+, you should be able to use `llvm-objdump -S -no-show-raw-insn my_file.o` to obtain a nicely formatted output.

Comment: `bcc` is also the name of [a 16-bit x86 compiler](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bcc).  I guess there are only so many letters in the alphabet, but I was very surprised for at first while skimming this.  Also BTW, you can just call the shell function `bcc`.  Why do you use an alias?

Comment: Also don't forget to quote your variable expansions:  `clang -O2 -Wall -emit-llvm -c "$@" -o -` |
`llc -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o "$(basename "$1" .c).o"`.  Note how `$()` allows easy nesting of double-quotes, compared to backticks.  I used `"$@"` in the clang command line, so you can pass `foo.c -O3 -Wextra -mtune=native` or whatever.  Hmm, I guess some of those optimization / tuning options would be needed on the `llc` command line?  So maybe `llc "${@:2}"` to pick up options other than $1.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. In this I copied the code directly from the man page. It's just an example, I guess the bcc project has a fine-tuned and polished call to llvm library. I think the reason why they aliased it is that the exact command was likely to evolve (for instance, `llvm-objdump -S` will need the `-g` flag at compile time). Anyway, the focus here was on the bytecode dump rather than on the compiling step. All this being said, your command remains valid, thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should file a bug report on the man page with the fix for their quoting.  That reasoning doesn't explain the `alias bcc=__bcc`, though.  You can redefine an already-defined shell function, so changing the contents of the function doesn't need an extra layer of indirection.  (Also, I think you missed the point about the other `bcc`.  It's an old project, and mostly only useful for making bootloaders.  16-bit x86 machine code is far more obsolete than 32-bit, and would be useless to the Linux kernel, because it runs in 32 or 64-bit mode!)

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually I'd tend to agree for the alias thing, in my own setup I got rid of it to be honest. Sorry I don't get it, what point did I miss? I see no relation with the 16-bit `bcc` compiler and anything else in the discussion—save the name of course. As far as I know the `bcc` set of tools for eBPF ([this](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc)) has no relation whatsoever with the 16-bit compiler. Did I sound differently?

Comment: Err, when you said "bcc project" in your previous comment, you probably weren't talking about the 16-bit C compiler.  Oops.  I'm only looking at this question because of the `[assembly]` tag.  I didn't even know `ebpf assembly` was a thing.  But I was curious, since I use Linux (including for my firewall, with iptables).  Anyway, so I read this answer to see what it was about :)

Comment: Oh I see, maybe in my answer it was not clear what I referred to with “bcc” as set of tools. Will edit.

Comment: Yeah, it's obvious that you must not be talking about Bruce's C Compiler (because it only makes 16-bit machine code) but that was the only bcc I'd ever heard of.

Comment: Sure. I assumed that someone that came for eBPF-related answers had heard about the set of tools. Of course, I should not have. I amended the answer, this should be clear now :-)

Comment: That's probably overkill, but it doesn't hurt :)  I was never really confused by the answer, I did realize that it must just be something else with the same name.  I had only skimmed it and didn't realize there was a "bcc project", and thought it was just a function-name you'd made up.  Thus when you said "*I guess the bcc project has a fine-tuned and polished call to llvm library*", I thought you *were* talking about Bruce's C Compiler at that point...  Everything's clear now, and I just wanted to let you know your answer was clear to start with (but I only skimmed it).

Comment: Thank you all, solved my confusion about linux ebpf, I will get more detail FYI.